# Как соединить формы?

Tags: html, php, вёрстка, form, javascript

Есть одна форма с отправкой в фаил "upload2.php" - это основной фаил.
И другая форма с отправкой в фаил "upload.php" - это необходимо для загрузки файлов он-лайн. Как их соединить?

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" oninput="log(event)" >
<input id="upload3" class="form-control" type="file" multiple="" name="upl">
    <form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input id="upload2" class="form-control" type="file" multiple="" name="upl">
    </form>
<input id="upload4" class="form-control" type="file" multiple="" name="upl">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма внутри формы это не хорошо.

Соединить в смысле чтобы при сабмите отправлялись обе? Скриптом только, на onsubmit одной формы сделать сабммит другой